# References appearing when uncited (natbib)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I'm having the problem in my document because it is showing uncited references in the list of references. If I was using bibtex I would use "\nocite", however with natbib this is not possible.

I'm using a template from an journal (that uses natbib), so I can't use bibtex. Is there any way to remove uncited references using natbib?

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. Please also clarify your question. How "to remove uncited references" and "I would use "\nocite"" seem to contradict each other since the only purpose of `\nocite` is adding a reference to the list of references without having to actually cite it in the document. Please clarify what kind of output you currently get and what exactly you would expect instead.

Comment: that is not correct. \nocite{*} does what you metioned. \nocite is a different thing

Comment: Would you mind providing a small example document that shows how you would use `\nocite` without an argument to exclude entries from the bibliography? As far as I know, `\nocite{*}` includes all references in the bib file into the list fo references without citing them in the document. `\nocite{key}` with the being the key of a single entry just adds this specific entry to the list fo references without citing it. If you don't want to include an entry from your bib file, just don't use `\cite`, `\nocite` or any related command on that key and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have a look at this minimal example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @book{Gnus,
    author = {David A. Zoo},
    title = {Gnats of the world},
    publisher = {Epic},
    Year = {2018},
    }
      @book{Gnats,
    author = {David A. TheZoo},
    title = {Gnus of the oceans},
    publisher = {Epic},
    Year = {2020},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
The first citation \citet{Gnus} and some text.
Here I cite \citet{Gnus} for the second time.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

showing how to use `natbib`. Why do you want to use `\nocite` unless you want to list all references in your bib file ?

Since you seem to be almost new here, the exemple is to be compiled using `latex` then `bibtex` then `latex`.

[image]